# SQL Server: Use exists on a table used in join

Tags: sql-server, join, stored-procedures, exists

Suppose I have a table `WorkItems` which has work items, their status and description. There are two more tables `Persons` and `WorkItemPersonLinks` which have the data of persons with work items assigned to them and the data of which item is assigned to which person respectively. The schema is like so -

```
Create table WorkItems 
(
    Id int not null primary key,
    Description varchar (100),
    Status varchar (30),
    IfValid bit not null,
)

Create table Persons
(
    Id int not null primary key,
    Name varchar (100),
    IfValid bit not null
)

Create table WorkItemPersonLinks
(
    Id int not null primary key,
    WorkItemId int foreign key references WorkItems(Id),
    PersonId int foreign key references Persons(Id),
    IfValid bit not null
)
```

Here is some sample data -

```
insert into workItems values
(1, 'Go Fishing', 'To do', 1), 
(2, 'Play video game', 'Done', 1), 
(3, 'Cook Dinner', 'In progress', 1), 
(4, 'Purchase Groceries', 'Done', 1)

insert into Persons values
(1, 'Tom', 1), (2, 'Dick', 1), (3, 'Harry', 1)    

insert into WorkItemPersonLinks values
(1, 1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2, 1), (3, 3, 3, 1), (4, 4, 2, 1),
(5, 2, 1, 1), (6, 3, 2, 1), (7, 3, 1, 1), (8, 4, 3, 1)
```

Here is what I want, suppose I have an input parameter `@viewOption` which can take possible values of `my` (only my work items), `done` (all done items), `not done` (Work items with `Status <> 'done'`) and `all` (all work items) and another parameter `@userId` which can have an `int` value and can be any one from the `Persons` table. So, let us say the user (Tom) wants to see only `his` tasks in which case `@viewOption = 'my'` and `@userId = 1` (Tom's Id in the `Persons` table.

**UPDATE**

A single work item can be assigned to multiple persons. So even if `@viewOption` is set to `my`, the query should return data of other persons assigned to that item (apart from the user) and not just his own data.

The query I am having a hard time making work is as below -

```
declare @viewOption varchar(10) = 'my'
declare @userId int = 1

select p.Name, wi.Description, wi.status from WorkItems wi
inner join WorkItemPersonLinks wpl on wi.Id = wpl.WorkItemId 
inner join Persons p on wpl.PersonId = p.Id
where wi.IfValid = 1 and wpl.IfValid = 1 and p.IfValid = 1 and ((@viewOption = 'my' and exists(select 1 from wpl where wpl.PersonId = @userId))
   or (@viewOption = 'all')
   or (@viewOption = 'done' and wi.Status = 'done')
   or (@viewOption = 'not done' and wi.Status <> 'done'))
```

There is this error `Invalid object name 'wpl` which I understand arises because of the context of the `exists` clause where it is invalid. I can make this to work by using `case` statements over `@viewOption` but wanted to double check for a better (and more elegant) way of doing this before I commit the query.

Comment: You can't use the the syntax `SELECT {Columns} FROM {Alias}` you have provide the object's name. Shouldn't, however, the `WHERE` clause of your `EXISTS` not just be part of the `ON` clause in your `JOIN` to `WorkItemPersonLinks`?

Comment: On a different note, the `WHERE` clause you have has the look of a Catch-all query. They can be real performance killers.[Revisiting Catch-all queries](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlinthewild/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/)

Comment: @Larnu - the `WHERE` clause inside of the `Exists` statement if attached to the `ON` clause will return only `my` tasks regardless of `@viewOption` unless I somehow accommodate that too..

Comment: Are you only having problem with the `my` part?

Comment: @SalmanA - Yes, if I remove the my part and pass any other value for `@veiwOption`, then the query seems to be returning correct results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the table name there rather than the local alias above, and also make a reference to the workitem:

```
select p.Name, wi.Description, wi.status 
from WorkItems wi
inner join WorkItemPersonLinks wpl on wi.Id = wpl.WorkItemId 
inner join Persons p on wpl.PersonId = p.Id
where wi.IfValid = 1 and wpl.IfValid = 1 and p.IfValid = 1 and 
   ((@viewOption = 'my' and exists 
     (select * from WorkItemPersonLinks w2 
      where w2.WorkItemId = wi.Id and w2.PersonId = @userId))
   or (@viewOption = 'all')
   or (@viewOption = 'done' and wi.Status = 'done')
   or (@viewOption = 'not done' and wi.Status <> 'done'));
```

Comment: Your query is almost what I wanted but just that it is only returning the data for the current user. However, it should also return the details of other persons if they are also assigned to the user's work items. I tweaked this query like so `WHERE WorkItemPersonLinks.PersonId = @userId AND WorkItemPersonLinks.WorkItemId = wpl.WorkItemId` and it worked...

Comment: @gkb, it was already like that and also returned other persons assigned to the workitem, no? Here is DBFiddle link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bc3206c700cd1d45c6c74d5a2941c128

Comment: Ah, I might have messed it up with my own work...desperation takes over your brain sometimes...-:)..I am accepting this as the answer..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Would the below work? If I understood correctly, you want to see results from the query if the UserID being passed in exists in the search query (where ViewOption is "My"). I've done this using IF statements to choose the best query to run, hopefully it works for you

```
declare @viewOption varchar(10) = 'my'
declare @userId int = 1

IF @viewOption = 'my' AND @userid IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        wpl.PersonId
    FROM
        WorkItems wi
        inner join WorkItemPersonLinks wpl on wi.Id = wpl.WorkItemId 
        inner join Persons p on wpl.PersonId = p.Id)
BEGIN
    SELECT
        p.Name,
        wi.Description,
        wi.status
    FROM
        WorkItems wi
        INNER JOIN WorkItemPersonLinks wpl on wi.Id = wpl.WorkItemId 
        INNER JOIN Persons p on wpl.PersonId = p.Id
    WHERE
        wi.IfValid = 1
        AND wpl.IfValid = 1
        AND p.IfValid = 1
END

IF @viewOption IN ('all', 'done', 'not done')
BEGIN
    SELECT
        p.Name,
        wi.Description,
        wi.status
    FROM
        WorkItems wi
        INNER JOIN WorkItemPersonLinks wpl ON wi.Id = wpl.WorkItemId 
        INNER JOIN Persons p ON wpl.PersonId = p.Id
    WHERE
        (@viewOption = 'all')
       OR (@viewOption = 'done' AND wi.Status = 'done')
       OR (@viewOption = 'not done' AND wi.Status <> 'done')
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
select p.name
    ,wi.description
    ,wi.status
from workitems wi
inner join workitempersonlinks wpl on wi.id = wpl.workitemid
inner join persons p on wpl.personid = p.id
where wi.ifvalid = 1
    and wpl.ifvalid = 1
    and p.ifvalid = 1
    and (
            (@viewoption = 'my' and wi.id in (select [WorkItemId] from  workitempersonlinks where PersonId =  @userid))
        or  (@viewoption = 'all')
        or  (@viewoption = 'done' and wi.status = 'done')
        or  (@viewoption = 'not done' and wi.status <> 'done')
    )
```